# Python Dataframe compute season wise performance compared to a reference (100%)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with seasons as a column. Each season has two variety items. I want to compute each season-wise performance of all items with one item `A`, where item `A` performance will be marked as 100%.

code:

```
xdf = pd.DataFrame({'Season':[1,1,2,2,3,3],'item':['A','B','A','B','A','B'],'value':[25,30,50,75,40,60]})

xdf = 
   Season item  value
0       1    A     25
1       1    B     30
2       2    A     50
3       2    B     75
4       3    A     40
5       3    B     60
```

Expected answer:

```
xdf = 
   Season item  value  %value
0       1    A     25   100   # This value(25) is taken as reference i.e. 100%
1       1    B     30   120   # Now value of `B` in Season 1 is 30. So, performance % = 30/25 *100
2       2    A     50   100   # This value(50) is taken as reference i.e. 100%
3       2    B     75   150   # Now value of `B` in Season 2 is 75. So, performance % = 75/50 *100
4       3    A     40   100   # This value(40) is taken as reference i.e. 100%
5       3    B     60   150   # Now value of `B` in Season 3 is 60. So, performance % = 60/40 *100
```

Comment: In question, you are saying `divide` but in the expected output, you are `multiplying`?

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish My apologies for the confusion. Now I corrected the question.

Comment: I have provided a better understanding of intended output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us create multiindex on `Season` and `item` in order to simplify calculation:

```
s = xdf.set_index(['Season', 'item'])['value']
xdf['%value'] = s.div(s.xs('A', level=1)).mul(100).tolist()
```

---

```
   Season item  value  %value
0       1    A     25   100.0
1       1    B     30   120.0
2       2    A     50   100.0
3       2    B     75   150.0
4       3    A     40   100.0
5       3    B     60   150.0
```

Comment: Interesting solution. What the `level=1` meaning here? how and why it is defined? Thanks

Comment: @Mainland `level=1`  parameter is used to tell the `xs` function that we would like to select the index value `A` from the second level of multiindex.

Answer (score 1):

If your rows are correctly ordered ('A' before 'B'), you can use `pct_change`. If needed sort by item first.

```
xdf['%value'] = xdf.groupby('Season')['value'].pct_change().fillna(0) * 100 + 100
print(xdf)

# Output
   Season item  value  %value
0       1    A     25   100.0
1       1    B     30   120.0
2       2    A     50   100.0
3       2    B     75   150.0
4       3    A     40   100.0
5       3    B     60   150.0
```

Comment: So, `pct_change()` is just like `diff()`. correct? First time I heard about `pct_change()` here. Really nice solution. The only reason this solution works is because first element after the grouping is `A`. How do we perform same evaluation if `B` is reference?, which comes second after the groupby

Comment: You can simply use `sort_values('item')` before. You can also convert your `item` column as `category` with ordered=True.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this function solve your problem.

```
df=xdf.copy()

for i in xdf['Season'].unique():
    _df = xdf[xdf['Season'] == i]
    idx = _df.iloc[1:].index
    val=_df.iloc[0].value
    for j in idx:
        cv=xdf.iloc[j].value
        xdf.at[j, 'value'] = (100/val)*cv
xdf.loc[xdf.groupby('Season')['value'].head(1).index, 'value'] = 100
df['%value']=xdf['value']

df
```